# Assign values to dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas

Having a `dataframe` as

```
  col
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

and another `dataframe` where i need to put calculated values from the previous `df`. the val column is a multiplication of values by index

```
i   j   val
1   1    1
1   2    2
1   3    3
2   1    2
2   2    4
2   3    6
3   1    3
3   2    6
3   3    9
```

ive tried to calculate it as using a loop but i dont think this approach is the fastest one. How can i accomplish this in a more efficient way?

Comment: Do you want the first dataframe to create the combination of `i` and `j`?

Comment: @ResidentSleeper yes the first DF should get the values for the second df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.col])).reset_index()
df2.columns = ['i', 'j']
df2['val'] = df2.i * df2.j

df2
Out[45]: 
   i  j  val
0  1  1    1
1  1  2    2
2  1  3    3
3  2  1    2
4  2  2    4
5  2  3    6
6  3  1    3
7  3  2    6
8  3  3    9
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
 df2['i'] = df.index
 df2['j'] = df.col
 df2['val'] = df2['j'] * df2['i']
```